# My prof is asking me to create objects but both classes are abstract

Tags: c++, oop

i have this OOP lab assignment , and i was asked to creat 2 classes that inherit from a parent class, both of these classes have pure virtual functions "virtual void merge(Book *ptr) = 0;".

then later in the assignment i was asked to create objects in the driver class, but both classes that i should be using to create the objects are abstract!

is there something i could do that creates the objects?
or is it just a mistake by the prof?

[The error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Obx.png)

I asked the prof and he said that no, nothing is wrong here, so i'm kinda lost.

Comment: You can't create an instance of an object of an abstract base class. You can have a pointer to one - but that still needs to be pointing to a "complete"/concrete class object. So you are either meant to implement the virtual functions in the derived class (i.e. override) or you may even need to create another level of class that inherits from these and implements the virtual functions.... it must be one of the two... or you have mis-understood the question - maybe you can print that?

Comment: post some code thar illustrates your problem

Comment: The easy thing to remember is you can't make an instance of an abstract class. You can make an instance of a class derived from the abstract class as long as all of the pure virtual functions are implemented somewhere in the class or its parents that lead up to the abstract class. You can have multiple abstract classes.

Comment: Your question is likely downvoted (I did not vote) because your [mcve] and errors need to be in the question and must be [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Likely your mentor wants you to override all pure-virtual functions to make these classes concrete. After that, you can instantiate them without any issues:

```
#include <string>

struct Book {
    virtual std::string genre() const = 0;
    virtual ~Book() = default;
};

struct FictionBook : Book {
    std::string genre() const override { return "Fiction"; }
};

struct NonFictionBook : Book {
    std::string genre() const override { return "NonFiction"; }
};

int main() {
    FictionBook fiction;
    NonFictionBook nonFiction;
}
```

Comment: well, i'm not sure that this is what he meant
because he specifically asked to make all "merge" functions pure-virtual
like it was mentioned in both classes "pure virtual merge(book *ptr )
:void"
Thanks for sharing this code though!

Comment: @ProblemsAllDay He might also want you to create a 3rd level (a different class that derives from this one and overrides the pure virtual functions).

Comment: i don't think the driver helps with the problem